# Error calling LibreOffice from Python

Tags: python, subprocess, converters, libreoffice

Calling LibreOffice to convert a document to text...

This works fine from the linux command line:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:"Text" document_to_convert.doc
```

But I get an error when I try to run the same command from Python:

```
subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'txt:"Text"', 'document_to_convert.doc'])
```

> Error: Please reverify input parameters...

How do I get the command to run from Python?

Comment: Is it possible that `txt:"Text"` should actually be 2 different arguments?

Comment: Ta, suggestions. 2 different arguments doesn't help. The doc doesn't need to be a string as its one word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the code you should use:

```
subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'txt:Text', 'document_to_convert.doc'])
```

This is the same line you posted, without the quotes around `txt:Text`.

**Why are you seeing the error?** Simply put: because soffice does not accept `txt:"Text"`. It only accepts `txt:Text`.

**Why is it working on the shell?** Your shell implicitly removes quotes around arguments, so that the command that gets executed is actually:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text document_to_convert.doc
```

Try running this command:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:\"Text\" document_to_convert.doc
```

Quotes won't be removed and you'll see the *Please verify input parameters* message you are getting with Python.

Comment: Ta, Andrea. V interesting. I had earlier copied the use of txt:"Text" from another user when txt:Text hadn't worked on the linux command line. Repeat: txt:Text hadn't worked. And neither was it working when called from Python. But now I try it, and it works from both. It is written that this command will fail if there are any existing LibreOffice instances running. I had since posting this message closed all open terminals just in case. I've been away and had lunch and now it works.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me on Linux as well, with 'libreoffice' command. I was trying to put all the parameters into the second argument to call(), turns out it's not right.