# Subprocess in Django 2.1.7

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, libreoffice, doc

So, my problem is pretty straight forward 
I want to execute the following shell command in Django 2.1.7

```
 libreoffice --headless --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" test.doc
```

**More info.**

I will be uploading a Doc file and want to convert it to txt. I was thinking if i could use the libreoffice to do so.
My server is Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6.7
I would be uploading the file in Media Root for now and then i would like to start the conversion.
Up till now I have tried to do the following:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def convertfiledoc(request):
    file = request.FILES['file']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(file.name, file)
    uploaded_file_url = 'media/'
    r = subprocess.call("libreoffice --headless --convert-to" +"txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" + "test.doc ")
    print(r)
    return Response(data={"message": uploaded_file_url}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Error is as follows**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libreoffice --headless --convert-totxt:Text (encoded):UTF8test.doc ': 'libreoffice --headless --convert-totxt:Text (encoded):UTF8test.doc '
```

I know that the function I have written is not complete but I was trying to do it to see if it works properly.

I even tried to hardcode the file but no success.

Comment: is libreoffice in your path? If not, you might need to provide the full path to libreoffice executable

Comment: the error shows `libreoffice` is not found. But your command is further also wrong, because you forget to add spaces before the 'test.doc' document name. And you should wrap the encoding in double quotes, so you need to escape them: `"... \"txt:Text (encoded):UTF8\" ..."` also here don't forget the space after "convert-to"

Comment: But also you need to split arguments to `subprocess.call` into separate elements of a list: `["libreoffice", "--headless",  "--convert-to..."]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error calling LibreOffice from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125574/error-calling-libreoffice-from-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
command=['libreoffice','--headless','--convert-to','txt:Text (encoded):UTF8','--outdir','test_dir','source_file.docx'] 
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: I had to go and check. But you are right, I had used the same thing you suggested. I just forgot to update my question. Thanks !